# Evaluate $\int\frac{1}{x}\coth(ax)\sin^2(\frac{xt}{2})dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I am trying to integrate this function:

### $\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x}\coth(\frac{\hbar x}{2kT})\sin^2(\frac{xt}{2})dx$

which Wolframalpha (for me) returns nothing, just a blank screen. I thought that it may be because it has no solution, or diverges, since removing $t$ from the equation had the same result. But if I try a definite integral such as:

$\int_0^{1000}\frac{1}{x}\coth(x)\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})dx$

[it clearly gives an answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28coth%28x%29*sin%5E2%28x%2F2%29%2Fx%29%20from%200%20to%201000).

But Wolfram also doesn't answer:

$\int_0^{1000}\frac{1}{x}\coth(x)\sin^2(\frac{xt}{2})dx$

Is there a solution to this integral, or at least a way to estimate a definite integral of it numerically?

Hopefully this may help some more. I am attemping to perform simulation along the lines of [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168900213013703) and it is Eq. 4 in the paper which I am attempting to resolve.

My attempt at figuring it out/simplifying it is as follows:

$\Gamma^x(t) = \frac{\hbar}{m_x}\int_0^\infty\frac{g^x(\omega)}{\omega}(\coth(\frac{\hbar\omega}{2k_bT})(1-\cos(\omega t)) - i\sin(\omega t)d\omega$

$ = \frac{\hbar g^x(\omega)}{m_x}\int_0^\infty\frac{2}{\omega}\coth(a\omega)\sin^2(\omega t/2)d\omega - \frac{i\hbar g^x(\omega)}{m_x}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}d\omega$

$ = \frac{2g^x(\omega)\hbar}{m_x}\int_0^\infty\frac{\coth(a\omega)\sin^2(\omega t/2)}{\omega}d\omega - \frac{ig^x(\omega)\hbar}{m_x}\frac{\pi t}{2} $

The $g^x(\omega)$ is evaluated out to a constant in my simulation, that is why I took it out of the integral, so my problem comes down to evaluating the $\coth(a\omega)$

Comment: What is $a$????

Comment: @Jan Simply a constant. Particularly in this case it is $\frac{\hbar}{2kT}$

Comment: do you want a definite or an undefinte integral?

Comment: A definite integral; but that requires getting the indefinite first, doesn't it?

Comment: No it doesn't see Residue theorem etc.

Comment: so what are the limits you wish?

Comment: In the paper the limits are $0$ and $\infty$, but any sufficiently large upper would work for estimation

Comment: For first, if you are looking for the value of the integral over $\mathbb{R}^+$, please state it, because to compute a nice closed form for the primitive is a terribly harder problem. Second, one parameter between $a$ and $t$ is useless, since you may remove it by a suitable change of variable. Third: why do you think such integral over $\mathbb{R}^+$ is convergent?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I updated it with more information. And I think it is convergent because I'm taking this from a [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168900213013703)  (eq.4  after some simplification.) and I can't imagine they use a divergent integral like that

Comment: @krakenwagon: the equation $4$ in the paper involves also a distribution that is likely to be (fast-)decaying at infinity. Without it, the integral is clearly divergent, since $\coth(x)$ converges very fast to $1$ and $\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}$ is not Lebesgue or improperly Riemann integrable over $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thank you, I believe I see my problem now.

Comment: if you do some "evil" things you can give this integral a value i guess